# SharePoint 2016 Ent. MinRole High Availability?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, minrole

deploying SharePoint 2016 with the new MinRole feature-set in HA Scenario, 4 servers in total - not including the SQL server.

I'm new to SP HA. Do i just install and configure each server and add to farm and then setup a HA via a windows feature? or is the config built into SharePoint itself?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HA with 4 servers means you have to select the appropriate the role for the each servers when you configuring your servers.

In 4 Servers HA, you have to select the following roles.

- 2 Servers with "Application with Search"
- 2 servers with "Front-end with Distributed Cache"
- You need a configure the load balancer in front of your WFE.

[Read this technet for more info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt743704(v=office.16).aspx)